# Access denied when asking for the count of all webs - SharePoint WSS 3.0 SP2

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I'm trying to list all the links on all the SharePoint web sites (parent and sub). When I'm logged in as the admin user it works just fine. However, when I sign on as a normal user I get an access denied error. And the error is thrown when I check the count property of the SPWebCollection.

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;

StringBuilder labelText = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < collWebsite.Count; i++) // <---- Access denied on count
{ // get links }
```

I tried adding giving my normal user full site control and I still received the access denied error. Any idea what access rule is being checked when accessing the count property?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use your application pool's account using the `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` method on `SPSecurity`.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
   SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
   SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;

   StringBuilder labelText = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < collWebsite.Count; i++) // <---- Access denied on count
   { // get links }
});
```

Comment: Look like there is a security action of demand on ObjectModel=true

Count property of SPWebCollection:
    public override int Count
    {
    [SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel=true)]
        get
        {
            this.EnsureWebsData();
            return this.m_strWebNames.Length;
        }
    }

Any idea where that permission is configured?

Comment: I get the same result if I use RunWithElevatedPrivileges